# Can't scrape listing links from a webpage using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape different listings for this search `Oxford, Oxfordshire` from this [webpage](https://www.zoopla.co.uk/) using requests module. This is how the [inputbox](https://img.incoherency.co.uk/4186) looks before I click the search button.

I've defined an accurate selector to locate the listings, but the script fails to grab any data.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/search/'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
params = {
    'view_type': 'list',
    'section': 'for-sale',
    'q': 'Oxford, Oxfordshire',
    'geo_autocomplete_identifier': 'oxford',
    'search_source': 'home'
}
res = requests.get(link,params=params,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html5lib")
for item in soup.select("[id^='listing'] a[href^='/for-sale/details/']:has(h2[data-testid='listing-title'])"):
    print(item.get("href"))
```

EDIT:

If I try something like the following, the script seems to be working flawlessly. The only and main problem is that I had to use hardcoded cookies within the headers, which expire within a few minutes.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cloudscraper

base = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk{}'
link = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/'
url = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/oxford/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': 'ajs_anonymous_id=caa7072ed7f64911a51dda2b525a3ca3; zooplapsid=cafe5156dd8f4cdda14e748c9270f623; base_device_id=68f7b6b7-27b8-429e-af66-366a4b64bac4; g_state={"i_p":1675619616576,"i_l":2}; zid=31173482e60549da9ccc1632e52a264c; zooplasid=31173482e60549da9ccc1632e52a264c; base_session_start_page=https://www.zoopla.co.uk/; base_request=https://www.zoopla.co.uk/; base_session_id=2315eaf2-6d59-4075-aeaa-6288af3efef7; base_session_count=8; forced_features={}; forced_experiments={}; active_session=anon; _gid=GA1.3.821027055.1675853830; __cf_bm=6.bEGFdT2vYz3G3iO7swuTFwSfhyzA0DvGoCjB6KvVg-1675853990-0-AQqWHydhL+/hqq8KRqOpCKDNtd6E96qjLgyOF77S8f7DpqCbMFoxAycD8ahQd7FOShSq0oHD//gpDj095eQPdtccDyZ0qu6GvxiSpjNP0+D7sblJP1e3Mlmxw5YroG3O4OuJHgBco3zThrx2SRyVDfx7M1zNlwi/1OVfww/u2wfb5DCW+gGz1b18zEvpNRszYQ==; cookie_consents={"schemaVersion":4,"content":{"brand":1,"consents":[{"apiVersion":1,"stored":false,"date":"Wed, 08 Feb 2023 10:59:02 GMT","categories":[{"id":1,"consentGiven":true},{"id":3,"consentGiven":false},{"id":4,"consentGiven":false}]}]}}; _ga=GA1.3.1980576228.1675275335; _ga_HMGEC3FKSZ=GS1.1.1675853830.7.1.1675853977.0.0.0'
}
params = {
    'q': 'Oxford, Oxfordshire',
    'search_source': 'home',
    'pn': 1
}

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
res = scraper.get(url,params=params,headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
container = soup.select_one("script[id='__NEXT_DATA__']").contents[0]
items = json.loads(container)['props']['pageProps']['initialProps']['regularListingsFormatted']
for item in items:
    print(item['address'],base.format(item['listingUris']['detail']))
```

How can I get content from that site without using hardcoded cookies within the headers?

Answer (score 5):

The following code example is working smoothly without adding headers and params parameters. The website's data isn't dynamic meaning you can grab the required data from the the static HTML dom but the main hindrance is that they are using Cloudflare protection. So to get rid of such restiction you can use either cloudscraper instead of `requests module` or selenium. Here I use cloudscraper and it's working fine.

**Script:**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
kw= ['Oxford', 'Oxfordshire']
data = []
for k in kw:
    for page in range(1,3):
        url = f"https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/oxford/?search_source=home&q={k}&pn={page}"
        page = scraper.get(url)
        #print(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
        for card in soup.select('[data-testid="regular-listings"] [id^="listing"]'):
            link = "https://www.zoopla.co.uk" + card.a.get("href")
            print(link)
            #data.append({'link':link})

# df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63903233/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63898182/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63898168/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63898177/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63897930/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63897571/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63896910/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63896858/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63896815/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63893187/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/47501048/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63891727/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63890876/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63889459/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63888298/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63887586/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63887525/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/59469692/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63882084/?search_identifier=4bf3e1bf22483c835fd89a5f17e16e2d
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63878480/?search_identifier=cbe92a4f0868061e26dff87f97442c6a
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/63877980/?search_identifier=cbe92a4f0868061e26dff87f97442c6a
```

... so on